# Where is the linux mint panel applets config file?

Tags: configuration-files, linux-mint, xfce

**OS:** Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
**DE:** xfce4
I have to set up several PCs and want to write a script which configures the launcher-applets in the panel. So the script would contain in the end something like:
`sudo cp ./my-predefined-config-file.type /path/to/location/`

[image: Where is the linux mint panel applets config file?]

**Edit:**
I figured out that the launchers are saved at the following file-path:
`/home/user/.config/xfce4/panel/`
However copying a launcher, from another system, into this directory does not make them appear in the panel:
`~$ cp -r  ~/Desktop/launcher-1/ ~/.config/xfce4/panel/`
So there must be still somewhere a config-file which i have to edit in order to make the launcher appear in the panel.

**PS:**
After changing something I am of course always reloading xfce in order to see the changes:
`~$ xfce4-panel -r && xfwm4 --replace`

Comment: If you are interested in cloning all panel settings, maybe [xfce4-panel-profiles](https://git.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-panel-profiles/) could be more useful, I just don't know if it offers any command line API.

Comment: @AndreLDM Actually I only wanted to clone the launchers, but [xfpanel-switch](https://git.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-panel-profiles/about/) seems to be even better! However, as you mentioned, I would need a terminal-based solution, so that i can include it to my existing bash script. Still thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

For the record, on my Linux Mint 19.2 with Cinnamon install (not: xfce4 as in the question), the panel launcher config file is at

```
~/.cinnamon/configs/panel-launchers@cinnamon.org/3.json
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow. It might be worth having a quick read over [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In particular, this question is asking specifically about configuring the panel for xfce, not cinnamon.

Comment: Well aware :) But upon searching it for cinnamon, I really only found this question for xfce, and figured it wouldn't hurt to also list the directory for cinnamon here (rather than posting and hen answering my own question...) since search engines find it anyway... uh well.

Comment: @rfl. then why didn't you say so in the answer?

Comment: huh, @Martian2020? I do... it says "Mint19.2 with Cinnamon" right there no?

Comment: I meant to add a disclaimer that this answer is not exactly for that question to make it clear.